# How can I calculate the dimension of the $\Bbb R$-vector space $\Bbb C²$

Tags: vector-spaces

The dimension of the $\Bbb R$- vector space of $\Bbb C$ is 2, but how does this translate to the vector space of $\Bbb C²$?

Comment: you mean the dimension? for $\Bbb C^2$ over $\Bbb R$ it's $4$

Comment: Yes, exactly. Sorry, forgot a word twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\{1,i\}$ is a basis for complex numbers $\Bbb C$ as a vector space over real numbers $\Bbb R$; the dimension is $2$.

A basis for $\Bbb C^2$ as a vector space over $\Bbb R$ is $\{(1,0), (i,0), (0, 1), (0,i)\};$ the dimension is $4$.

In general, a complex vector space of dimension $n$ is a real vector space of dimension $2n$.

Answer (score 1):

In general you can prove the following:

Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ of dimension $\text{dim}_{\mathbb{C}}(V) = n$. If you choose a basis $v_1,\dots, v_n \in V$ of $V$ as a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space, then $v_1,\dots, v_n,iv_1,\dots, iv_n \in V$ is a basis of $V$ as a $\mathbb{R}$-vector space. That means we have $\text{dim}_{\mathbb{R}}(V) = 2n$. You can apply that to your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Since C² = C x C = R² x R² = R x R x R x R

=> C² has 4 unit vectors

=> Base has 4 Elements

=> dimension of the R-vector space of (C²) = 4.